# How to decode this string?

Tags: soap, encoding, utf-8

I'm working with SOAP and I've received the following XML values.

```
<Name>&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F; &#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;</Name>
```

The sender told me that this is in Russian, but I have no idea how to decode it. When I decode it in .net, all I get is "???????"

Is that even a valid encoded string? What's this called?

Comment: If it's UTF-8 with the bytes as HTML character entities, then the string is "<Name>ИмяИмяИмяИмя ИмяИмяИмяИмя</Name>".

Comment: MRAB // yes, that's exactly what the sender said. How did you decode it?!

Comment: I used Python 3: `import re; string = b"<Name>&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F; &#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;&#xD0;&#x98;&#xD0;&#xBC;&#xD1;&#x8F;</Name>"; re.sub(br"&#x(\w+);", lambda m: bytes([int(m.group(1), 16)]), string).decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like html-entities to me.
To decode it you need the source encoding. For example KOI8-R

You could try around with this tool: http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en
It's a Universal online Cyrillic decoder